# Terraform Modules - Variables and .tfvars

Tags: variables, module, terraform

Having an issue with Terraform modules and variables and I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong.

I have a folder structure that looks like this;

```
Accounts
    |_____Account1
    |        Main.tf
    |        terraform.tfvars
    |_____Account2
    |_____Account3
    |_____Modules
             |________VPC
                      Main.tf
                      Variables.tf
```

In my modules folder I have my main.tf and variables.tf, under the accounts I also have my main.tf (calling module vpc) and terrform.tfvars.

How can I use my terraform.tfvars to pass secure credentials to my main.tf, within my accounts folder?

Variables in my Variables.tf within the VPC module look like so;

```
variable "aws_access_key" {
  default = ""
 }
```

Within my account folders, in the Main.tf I am trying to call tfvars this way;

```
variable "aws_access_key" {}

module "VPC" {
source = "/Accounts/Modules/VPC"
aws_access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
}
```

Can run terraform init without any issues but trying to run terraform plan, it just comes up in red and fails to run. This does work if I enter the variables into my main.tf within the account folder manually. But I want to strip out anything sensitive into a .tfvars file, that will end up else where.

I hope I am doing something obviously wrong! Have also tried the -var-file=terraform.tfvars switch from within account1's folder.

Any idea's would be great. As everything I read tend to imply this should be working.

Thanks
Stephen

[image]

Comment: I recreated the setup you have above and was able to get it to plan without issue.  What is the specific error message that terraform is giving you?

Comment: Thanks jstill - least I am not crazy! So when I try and run this I just get the terraform help output in red, as if I am entering the wrong syntax - all I am doing is running this in one of the account folders - terraform plan

Comment: Can you include a screenshot showing the `terraform plan` line in your console and the first few lines of the output after?  I feel like I've had a client run into something like this before, hoping seeing that might jog my memory.

Comment: Yes, please ads the error message, but not as a screenshot but as text, please.

Comment: So you're doing a get, then a plan.  Is there any change if you do get, init, then plan?

Comment: Well I've just struggled to get a screen up so will stick with that!! But yes I have tried it all - get, init, then plan. At a loss as to what this could be - tempted just to start it all again. Everything passes a validate also for syntax when I run it in the folders

Comment: Definitely nothing jumps out as wrong.  Are you using the latest version?  If not, try upgrading and see if that changes anything (warning though: if you're using shared state it'll upgrade the state, so everyone would have to upgrade).  Also, make sure you don't have any random non-printing characters floating around in any of the files.  That was the issue I'd seen before that I couldn't remember.  Maybe just verify character encoding on all the tf files, to be sure.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go back to a fresh setup and slow add in my code - see if there is something knocking around. Only thought this would be a quick thing to see how much stuff we have is re-usable :-) - Thanks Again! - Good shout on the shared state aswell! Something I am also looking at moving to - will remember that about upgrading

Comment: We recently learned in a GitHub issue that Terraform is erroneously returning this usage message in the case of a syntax error in one of the `.tfvars` files, whether it's one explicitly given on the command line or one selected by default. This is going to be fixed in the next major release.

Comment: Martin, thats interesting I am thinking I have an error somewhere hidden in that file set. Rebuilding it now seems to be fine. Wonder if there is a syntax error if it could be identified when running the plan command rather than left guessing. Though nothing in a validate command came back as bad for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ran this from a fresh folder - taking only part of my config and is running fine - so must be something in the file. If anyone else comes across this